# Unity 3D not Working on Acer D270 w/ Intel GMA 3600

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, unity-2d, acer

I recently bought myself an Acer Aspire One D270 with the GMA 3600 graphics chipset thinking I would get some lovely graphics. However, I am stuck using Unity 2D and I cant figure out how to enable 3D. None of the fixes I have found so far have worked. Another effect of this is that I cant change the backlight brightness. So whenever I open the lid, looking at the screen is like staring into the sun.

Is there a driver for it in the works? Does the 3.4 kernel support the chipset and most of all is there a way to fix this? Please help

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu related problem. Intel doesn't provide a 3d capable Linux driver, and probably never will. Check out this bug report for more info: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/934956 I'd strongly recommend getting a Linux friendly hardware next time you shop around.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. Could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get an Acer Aspire One D270 working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144768/how-do-i-get-an-acer-aspire-one-d270-working)

Answer (score 0):

You can only get a better resolution than 800*600, and after many settings changes, for 1024*600 at this time...and the driver freeze after standby so you have to push shutdown button and press enter...

Sorry for my bad english, I'm french.

To get the 1024*600 resoltion it's here : http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=852521&p=1